# Elasticsearch aggregation to extract pattern and occurrences

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, pattern-matching, aggregation

I have trouble formulating what I'm looking for so I'll use an example:

You put 3 documents in elasticsearch all with a field "name" containing these values: "test", "superTest51", "stvv".

Is it possible to extract a regular expression like pattern with the occurrences? In this case:

- "xxxx": 2 occurrences
- "x{5}Xxxx99": 1 occurrence

I've read some things about analyzers, but I don't think that's what I'm looking for.

Edit: To make the question clearer: I don't want to search for a regex pattern, I want to do an aggregate on a regular expression replaced field. For example replace [a-z] with x. Is the best way really to do the regular expression replace outside of elasticsearch?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the formulation of your request, not sure this will match what you are looking for, but assuming you mean to **search based on regex** , 
following should be what you are looking for:

[wildcard and regexp queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_wildcard_and_regexp_queries.html)

Do take note that the behavior will be different whether the field targeted is analyzed or not.
Typically if you went with the vanilla setup of Elasticsearch as most people to start, your field will likely be analyzed, you can check your the events mapping in your indices to confirm that.

Based on your example and assuming you have a not_analyzed *name* field:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "name": "[a-z]{4}"
    }
  }
}

GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "name": "[a-z]{5}[A-Z][a-z]{3}[0-9]{2}"
    }
  }
}
```

Based on your update, and a quick search (am not that familiar with aggregations), could be something like the following would match your expectations:

```
GET _search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "regmatch": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "xxxx": {
            "regexp": {
              "name": "[a-z]{4}"
            }
          },
          "x{5}Xxxx99": {
            "regexp": {
              "name": "[a-z]{5}[A-Z][a-z]{3}[0-9]{2}"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will give you 3 counts:
- total number of events
- number of first regex match
- number of second regex match

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's not really what I had in mind, I updated my question to make it more clear.

Comment: This would mean I have to make a custom regex filter for every pattern that my data could contain, while I want to find all possible patterns in my data and their frequency.

Comment: Then I'm a bit puzzled as to how you'd expect ElasticSearch to provide you with that, considering that for an entry like "test" for example, **some** valid regex patterns matching would be: `test` `[a-z]est`, `[a-z]{4}`, `[a-z]{4,}`. the number of possible matching patterns is huge, for each of your events. guessing the ones you want to take into account seem difficult ...

Comment: I'd like elasticsearch to do a regular expression replace, that I can give. For example replace [a-z] with x, [A-Z] with X, ... and to let me do aggregations on that new value.